# Enable OpenCL with OpenCvSharp

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, opencl

I am using OpenCvSharp to despeckle an image (GaussianBlur + AddWeighted). It take ~1-2 second for a relatively small image (1000*1500 pixels), depending of the GaussionBlur ksize parameter. Apparently OpenCV can make use of OpenCL to leverage the graphic card power. So, I wonder why it is so slow with a quite recent graphic card (GTX 960).

Is there a OpenCvSharp setting to enable OpenCL?
(I tried Cv2.SetUseOptimized(true) with almost no, if some, change)

Comment: I tested 2500x1900 image for gaussianblur on a crap computer, it took 150ms. Kernel size was 121x121, sigma was 100ish. CPU usage was around %15 and no gpu usage. setThreadNum didn't increase speed. Because I did not re-build that project in my computer, just got it from nu-get. You should re-build it on your computer then it should work.